# The relation between decay of particle in different reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, soft-question

I am reading the Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay Is all the mathematical relation mentioned in the link is valid for any reference fame? What I mean by reference frame is related to :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inertial_reference_frame

The question: is the particle decay relations is valid in both the reference frame mentioned above? Or reference frame is not related to the equations of particle decay? I was expecting that particle decay relation is a function of reference frame. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Go back to the decay of a muon, as in the  basic illustration of muon decay to illustrate time dilation. We link the frame of reference of the muon with our frame  using Lorentz transformatiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas for radioactive decay are generally valid only in the rest frame of the decaying system.

This is the reason why we can observe unstable particles in cosmic rays from the sun, which would have long decayed if their half life would refer to the center of mass of the earth.